# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager not work in my php application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
$graph = new Graph();
   $graph
      ->setBaseUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/")
      ->setApiVersion("v1.0")
      ->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);


 return $me = $graph->createRequest("get", "/me/manager")
                ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
                ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                ->setTimeout("1000")
                ->execute();
```

**Showing error is**

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Cache-Control: private Transfer-Encoding:
>   chunked Content-Type: application/json request-id:
>   b343d567-e1e2-4f46-8bd1-d80d27cf28ab client-request-id:
>   b343d567-e1e2-4f46-8bd1-d80d27cf28ab x-ms-ags-diagnostic:

```
{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Southeast Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_18","ADSiteName":"SEA"}}
Duration: 35.3167
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Wed, 31 Oct 2018 11:57:45 GMT

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b343d567-e1e2-4f46-8bd1-d80d27cf28ab",
      "date": "2018-10-31T11:57:46"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe access denied error means that you have not requested the right permission scopes in the application you registered. /me/manager requires specific scopes as documented here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_manager.

Permission type Permissions (from least to most privileged)
Delegated (work or school account)  User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All

You can actually break into your code and check the access token you are receiving back from signing in and consenting. Use https://jwt.ms/ and you'll see the scopes that are embedded in the token.